# pushControllerWithName not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I'm trying to push an interface controller with the identifier "InterfaceControllerTodoItemTapped" programmatically (deployment target iOS 8.2) when a WKInterfaceTable row is tapped:

```
[self pushControllerWithName:@"InterfaceControllerTodoItemTapped" context:nil];
```

The source controller is part of a page-based navigation setup.

The identifier field of the receiving interface controller is set to "InterfaceControllerTodoItemTapped".

**Problem:** Although the above push command is reached (confirmed using a breakpoint), the InterfaceControllerTodoItemTapped is not shown and its method awakeWithContext is not being called (confirmed using a breakpoint).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/InterfaceStyles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH12-SW1) states that one has to choose either a page-based or a hierarchical navigation. They are mutually exclusive.

Therefore, presenting a controller using pushControllerWithName does not work with page-based navigation.

The solution is to present the controller modally using the following method:

```
[self presentControllerWithName:@"InterfaceControllerTodoItemTapped" context:nil];
```

Comment: I am able to push control new watchOS 6 and above but not  able to push wkinterface in watch series2 watch is 5.3 with page based navigation. Any solution

Answer (score 6):

If the Interface Controller you are pushing is **hierarchical navigation** then make sure -

> **Identifier** field in *Attributes Inspector* is set.

```
[self pushControllerWithName:@"SSWatchTableInterfaceController" context:nil];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 5+ Versions**

```
self.pushController(withName: "SecondWKVC", context: nil)
```